# How to call auto of reutrn function in node js

Tags: node.js

On the time of page loaded get_switch() function which globally created on app.js page will be call then return a method. i want to execute these return methods.

demo.js

```
  const return_functions = get_switch('BTC');

   function get_btc()
  {
    console.log('btc');
  }


 function get_bch()
 {
   console.log('bch');

 }
```

app.js

```
  global.get_switch=function(coin_name){

 switch(coin_name){

 case 'BTC':
 return 'get_btc()';
 break;


  case 'BCH':
  return 'get_bth()';
  break;

  default:
 console.log('default');
 }

 }
```

As shown in example above i have passed BTC in get_switch. and that function return us get_btc() function. so i want to call get_btc function on same time.

If this is not possible in this way so please guide me with your idea and suggest me how can i do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

demo.js

```
var obj = {
    get_btc: function get_btc() {
        console.log('btc');
    },
    get_bth: function get_bth() {
        console.log('get_bth');
    }
}
const return_functions = get_switch('BTC');
if (return_functions) {
    obj[return_functions]();
}
```

app.js

```
global.get_switch = function (coin_name) {

    switch (coin_name) {
        case 'BTC':
            return 'get_btc';
            break;
        case 'BCH':
            return 'get_bth';
            break;
        default:
            console.log('default');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var get_switch=function(coin_name){
    switch(coin_name){
        case 'BTC':
            get_btc();
            break;
        case 'BCH':
            get_bth();
            break;
        default:
            console.log('default');
    }
}

get_switch('BTC');

function get_btc() {
    console.log('btc');
}

function get_bch() {
    console.log('bch');
}
```